# JavaScript store Function Call inside Array Index

Tags: javascript, html, web

I been stuck with this problem for a while.

All I need is to put a link inside an array that will call a function to change some text.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">The link</p>
<p id="demo1">This content should be be changed when I click the text above</p>

<script>

var text = ["<a href=javascript:Test(demo1, milk)>Click me to change text below to milk</a>"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text[0];

function Test(id, content){
var container = document.getElementById(id);
container.innerHTML = content;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This works if the link is placed outside an array, but inside an array it doesn't.

Any pointers on how I can get this to work? Been trying for 8 hours now. Thanks guys I would really appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the quotes, the arguments should be wrapped.

```
var text = ["<a href=javascript:Test(demo1,milk)>Click me to change text below to milk</a>"];
```

should be

```
var text = ["<a href=javascript:Test('demo1','milk')>Click me to change text below to milk</a>"];
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/zitamago/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the input, let me check it out and see if it works. :)

Comment: Alright! It's working. Thanks for the input. Been at this for 12 hours and have been looking into alternative approaches like eval. Didn't know it was just the quotation marks. Again thanks. :D